# What are the coordinates of Trango Towers?

Tags: mountains, pakistan, himalayas

What are the coordinates of [Trango Towers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trango_Towers)? I could see **35°46′N 76°11′E** on Wikipedia, however they [aren't visible](https://goo.gl/maps/87ZbKkFwMdH2) on Google Earth.

Answer (score 2):

I get coordinates of [35.6828376,76.1651133](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Trango+Group/@35.6828376,76.1651133,11924a,20y,39.71t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x38e4d8d257b36ed1:0xf4b61a5b704524d!8m2!3d35.7730556!4d76.1813889) when I type in 'Great Trango Tower' into Google, and the 3D view looks like it might be right.

[Google maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Trango+Group/@35.6828376,76.1651133,11924a,20y,39.71t/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x38e4d8d257b36ed1:0xf4b61a5b704524d!8m2!3d35.7730556!4d76.1813889)

Comment: I got the same but 3D view doesn't look like Trango Towers.